# Image texture not following the animation

Tags: animation, texturing, rigging, node-editor, texture-coordinates

File here: [image]

Absolute newbie here. I made this eye texture following a tutorial on Youtube as part of a character. When I animate the character the texture from the eye sort of lags behind until the eye becomes completely red with a blue empty circle in the middle. I'm trying to find a solution but I'm completely lost tbh- sorry if a similar question has been asked, I did check but couldn't find anything that works

[image: how it should look]

[image: texture begins to lag behind]

[image: eye goes red]

Comment: hello, please share your file with this site (read the instructions): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots I've done it now, sorry!

Comment: Yes I've noticed that when you use the Texture Coordinate "Object" output, the material won't follow if your object is rigged, which was not the case in 2.7. You can use another output socket,but maybe someone knows how to fix it. Could you also please link the tutorial?

Comment: This is the tutorial. I know I didn't quite do it right but it was good enough for what I need/want right now https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcHX4AT1vtg&t=1948s&ab_channel=CGCookie

Comment: @moonbots You mean changing from object texture coordinate to the other options? I tried doing that but I don't think any of them seemed to work... :(

Comment: He doesn't rig his eye so we can't see how he would fix the problem. Yes I mean using another output but it would mean changing some settings in your nodes. I hope someone will know how to fix this, again it seems to work differently since 2.8...

Comment: For example you could unwrap your mesh and use the UV output. By the way, do you have a reason to work with high-poly meshes? It slow down the animation in the 3D view...

Comment: Oh yeah, that was just me, I just needed the eye to look realistic which is why I followed the tutorial. I think I was trying to smooth the eye... How do I fix that if it's a problem?

Comment: I'll wait and hopefully someone might have a solution to the rigging issue. Thank you @moonbots!

Comment: "Generated" texture coordinates should avoid this issue. Though, you'll have to remap all the texture coordinates of the shaders.

Comment: I've made Generated texture coordinates. I pretty much am just playing around so don't really know what I'm doing but I've managed a slightly less pretty eye where the texture does follow the frame. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As opposed to *"object"* texture coordinates, *"generated"* texture coordinates will stay stable "around the mesh" when the mesh is animated.

[image]

As *"object"* texture coordinates, at starting point, are here roughly between -1 and 1 (nearly a sphere) and *"generated"* texture coordinates are between 0 and 1, we can scale by 2 and remove 1 to go from the second to the first.

[image]

So that you can chain this mapping with the existing one, for instance:

[image]

or if you prefer you can also tune the value manually.

[image]

Comment: Oh my God, thank you so much lemon!!! This is amazing and so well explained. Thanks!